# how to get database username and password in hive

Tags: apache, hadoop, jdbc, hive, hiveql

Am writing jdbc program to connect hive database. I want the username and password to give it in the connection url.

I don't know how to get the username and password using hive QL.
Can anybody help me out??

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [DataDirect][Hive JDBC Driver]A value was not specified for a required property: PASSWORD
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.hivebase.ddcp.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.hivebase.ddcp.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.hivebase.ddco.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.hivebase.ddco.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.hive.HiveImplConnection.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.hivebase.BaseConnection.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.hivebase.BaseConnection.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.hivebase.BaseConnection.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.hivebase.BaseConnection.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.hivebase.BaseDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at hivejdbcconnection.HiveJdbcConnection.main(HiveJdbcConnection.java:33)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: am getting above error if i used username "hive" and password "".

Comment: Check for the details in the hive-site.xml. It has username and password details

Answer (score 11):

To get hive username and password, go to `hive-site.xml` and search for `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName` and `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword`. The values of these properties are your hive username and password respectively.

(Default values are `APP` and `mine` for username and password which can be found in `hive-default.xml`)

In case, if you don't have such property in hive-site.xml. Then add these lines in `hive-site.xml`:

```xml
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hiveuser</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>hivepass</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoop</value>
</property>
```

Note: I have a database named hadoop in mysql for hive. Thats why the value for `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` is `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoop`.

After setting or finding your username and password, use it as follows:

```java
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "hiveuser", "hivepass");
```

Use your `hive database name` instead of `default`. Hope it helps!!!!

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` for jdbc connection? If yes, then you have to create a database in MySQL. Did you try restarting hadoop processes after changing configuration?

Comment: No am not using Mysql for jdbc connection. Am directly connecting to hive database and printing the data  within a table. @rajesh

Comment: You will need a metastore that stores hive table details. Refer this page http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html.

Answer (score 0):

hive default user name is **hive**

use the below connection string for hiveserver2

```
"jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "hive", ""
```

for **hiveserver1** default is empty,hiveserver2 also works with empty username and password.

```
jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default
```

Driver name: `org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`

Username and password are empty

read the link [Connecting to Hive using Beeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113323/connecting-to-hive-using-beeline/29115976#29115976)

Comment: what is the password for user 'hive??@sravan'

Comment: password is  just leave  like this  ""

Comment: Am not using default database.I created my own database.can u tell me how to get the username and password for my database? @saravan

Comment: is it not working with this "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/yourdatabase", "hive", ""

Comment: are you able to connect with beeline. use empty user and  empty password "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/yourdatabase", "", ""

Comment: Is there any hive query to retrieve username and password of a database? @sravan

Comment: post your db connection code. how did you set uname and passwd to database.

Comment: default username and password which are worked for me are "scott" and "tiger" :) :)